# Android AlertDialog.Builder Custom title bar with Edit text

Tags: android

Here is the issue, I want to create a custom alert dialog box with 4 parts,

1. Title Bar
2. Header part (Most of the time I plan to use EditText box for
   searching purpose)
3. List item(Single click or Multi Click)
4. Footer part(Cancel or OK buttons)

I try do this using separate layout, but list view item not showing properly(shrinking). So then I plan to use AlertDialog and inside I have implemented ListView and footer button part in single LinerLayout and set it using setView method, it solved my list view and Footer issue.

Problem is I want to add Header part top of the list view.

Image Link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4048078/device-2013-07-31-141546.png

Comment: i doubt a title is supposed to be editable.

Comment: Design a layout with `edittext` as the first field. In code you need to mention like `settitle(null)` and use my code at [below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965830/android-alertdialog-builder-custom-title-bar-with-edit-text/17966045#17966045)

Comment: thanx guys, I did that using dialog class.

Comment: @Dimal why did you tick and untick now for my answer if you use it

Comment: @Kartheek it's a mistake dude. thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Dialog dialog_help = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog_help.setContentView(R.layout.title_multi_selectitems_dialog);
EditText et_1 = (EditText) dialog_help.findViewById(R.id.et_help_1);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
dialog_help.setCancelable(true);
dialog_help.setTitle("   Help   ");
dialog_help.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
dialog_help.show();
dialog_help.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
dialog_help.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to set editBox in the title of the alert dialog.
To set title use `setTitle` and `setIcon` builder methods.

EditText it the control that's better to place in dialog,s body.
Use [AlertDialog.Builder.setView(android.view.View)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) for this.